# Gllamm, gllapred and correct way of plotting results?

Tags: stata

I am trying to run a random intercept, random coefficient (usually referred to as random slope) multilevel logit model for cross-sectional data with cross-level interactions in Stata with the command `gllamm`. So, my code would be something like this;

```
> gen cons = 1
> gen inter = cons
> gen slope = IV3

> gllamm dv iv1 iv2 iv3 iv3iv4 iv4, i(country) link(logit) family(binomial) adapt nrf(2) eqs(inter slope)
```

where `iv1 - iv3` are the level-1 variables, `iv3` is dichotomous and its slope / coefficient is let to vary, `iv4` is the level-2 variable and `iv3iv4` is the cross-level interactions.

After running `gllamm`, what I actually wanted was something like the Stata command

```
> margins, dydx (iv3) at(iv4=(1(10)100))
```

would do. If I am correct, something similar can be obtain with the command

```
> gllapred prob, mu marg
```

However, here comes the problem. When I want to plot the marginal predicted probabilities as a function of my level-2 `iv4` for the two groups of the dichotomous `iv3` separately using the code

```
> twoway (line prob iv4 if iv3==0, sort) (line prob iv4 if iv3==1, sort),
> ytitle(Predicted marginal probability) xtitle(iv4)
> legend(order(1 "no" 2 "yes"))
```

what I obtain is not a nice plot with a smooth curve, but with a line that goes up and down at each value of `iv4`!

I saw people using the

```
> sort
```

command after `gllapred` and before `twoway`, but I am not sure I understand how it works. Nevertheless, I tried for example

```
> sort iv3 country iv4
```

and then

```
> twoway
```

but the plot does NOT look the same! 
My main question is; is there a problem with my data, or is it about how I rearrange the syntax or the data? What does my plot actually say? Is there a way for me to obtain a nice smooth line?

Comment: You've asked the same question on CV and SO. Please don't do that. Advice to post in just one place is given at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic My own view is that your question makes more sense on SO.

Answer (score 1):

`margins` averages over the values of all other variables. Since `iv1` and `iv2` vary from observation to observation, your line is jiggly. You may want to replace the remaining variables at their means before `gllapred` (backing up the original values, of course).

Comment: I would like to do the computation of the discrete or partial change in probability for each of the values of an independent variable averaged across the observed values of all other independent variables, referred to as average marginal effects (AME) and not marginal effects at the mean (MEM - marginal effects at fixed values of the independent variables like means). That is what I did in the micro-level model earlier (like `margins, dydx(iv3) at (iv4=(1(10)100))`, and I hope it is possible to apply also at the multi-level model.(?)